# Is there a way to separate Grouping based off of time occurence in CollectionViewSource WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, collectionview

So I have a datagrid with three columns: TimeStamp, Title, and Message. Let's say I press button A which generates Title A, with a message and timestamp where all of it will be recorded

Right now my WPF form is grouping it based off of the title:

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
     <PropertyGroupDescriptions PropertyName="Title" />
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

Let's say I press a different button, Button B, where it generates Title B and message and timestamp. With this it will create a different group to separate it from other existing groups.

Now if I want to press Button A, the title, message and timestamp will be appended to the first group. I want to figure out how to separate it to create a new group. Is there a way to do that?

I was thinking of changing the title and adding a number 2 to it and increment the value if more new groups pop up but that isn't appealing to the end user.

Answer (score 0):

You could add another `PropertyGroupDescription`.

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
     <PropertyGroupDescriptions PropertyName="Title" />
     <PropertyGroupDescriptions PropertyName="TimeStamp" />
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

This adds sub-groups as in:
**Title A**
*TimeStamp A* 
Message 1 
Message 2 
*TimeStamp B* 
Message 4 
Message 5

**Title B**
*TimeStamp A* 
Message 3

Comment: I do not want it to be grouped with timestamp. Not only I do not want to see it on the datagrid, but I do not want to have multiple entries within the group because some timestamps are seconds different from each other. It is better if there's a clean look of all of them grouped together by title on the front end, while on the backend it is also grouped with timestamp

Comment: Then I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve. Could you type or draw how it's supposed to look?